# Creating excel file in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, excel-interop

Its my first experience with excel file using C#.

As a demo, I wrote a single line in excel file and it worked but now I am trying to insert all the rows of DataTable but it gives the following error:

*"HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"*

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = table.Rows[i]["Ref"].ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = table.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
}
```

Please tell me how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Range.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff195193) instead. [`Worksheet.Cells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194567.aspx) property is readonly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = table.Rows[i]["Ref"].ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value = table.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1 for a correct solution, but note that the problem is not (only) that Cells is read-only; it's that C# does not invoke the default property.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a DataTable, put all the values into a `object[,]`

Then you can assign them in one swoop:

```
using (var targetRangeHeader = _excelApp.Range[TargetRangeTopAddress].WithComCleanup())
 using (var targetRangeFirstDataCell = targetRangeHeader.Resource.Offset[1, 0].WithComCleanup())
  using (var targetRange = targetRangeFirstDataCell.Resource.Resize[MyObjectArrayValues.Length, 1].WithComCleanup())
{
 targetRange.Resource.Value2 = MyObjectArrayValues;
```

Using http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop

Answer (score 0):

I wholeheartedly endorse Jeremy Thompson's answer to use a 2-dimensional object array.  The performance will be orders of magnitude faster.  I'm writing to explain why the code you've written doesn't work (and why you probably thought it should work).

In Visual Basic, there's a concept of "Default" property.  When you write this in VBA, you're using that concept:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1) = someValue
```

The Cells property returns a Range object.  In VBA, since you haven't used the Set keyword, this line is not reassigning the value of the object (and, if you added the Set keyword, it would fail to reassign the value of the object, since it's a read-only property, as Ria notes).

The absence of the Set keyword causes the assignment to go to the default prpoperty of the Range object returned by `Cells(i, 1)`.  The default property, of course, is the Value property.  The above VBA sample, in other words, is equivalent to this:

```
Dim r As Range

Set r = xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1)
r.Value = someValue
```

Of course, you can also skip the `r` variable:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = someValue
```

Now, C# doesn't have the default property concept.  You're therefore unable to write this code the shortcut way, which leads us to the code suggested in Ria's answer:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = someValue;
```

Or, with the real value instead of `someValue`:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = table.Rows[i]["Ref"].ToString();
```

The default property makes it easy for beginners to write code, and it helps code to be concise, but it's also confusing for people who are between the beginner stage and the advanced stage.